# How to block a script loading with chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I make my extension's `inject.js` so it blocks certain scripts on the page from loading?

Also, how can I make my extensions JS file load FIRST rather than at the end?

Comment: If those scripts are loaded from an URL you can block it with chrome.webRequest, otherwise you'll have to rewrite the page ([example](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14164-kinozal-tv-remove-external-scripts/code)). In Firefox it's [much easier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData).